# subscripts in sympy and python

Tags: python, sympy

I'm learning sympy and python by studying sample codes I found online.  I came across this line of code

```
z = symbols("z_{0:2}")
```

which creates the variables z_0 and z_1.  This is very handy!  Now, the z_{0:2} construction reminds me of the range function in basic python.  My question:  Is this  z_{0:2}  an ad-hoc trick just for defining variables with subscripts, or is this a special instance of a general sympy/python construction?  If so, what is this general construction, and can you point me to a couple of onlin documentation where I can learn more about this?

I'm a complete newbie; thanks for your patience.

Comment: [`sympy.core.symbol.symbols`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.symbol.symbols)

Comment: @MechanicPig:  Thanks for the reference.  There they explain how to use e.g. symbols('x5:10')  to define the variables x5, x6, x7, x8, x9, which is great, but I don't see any reference for the *subscript* -- the underscore part in z_{0:2}.  Is that a python or sympy construction?  What's the official name for it?  Thanks!

Comment: Similar to their example, `symbols('z_{0:2}')` can obtain `(z_{0}, z_{1})`, with the exception of parentheses. This is a purely sympy construction of its own, independent of Python.

Comment: Here is almost everything they have done: [symbol.py#L768-L804](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/d2be7bacd2604e98a642f74028e8f0d7d6084f78/sympy/core/symbol.py#L768-L804)

Comment: To the Python interpreter, `"z_{0:2}"` is just a string that it passes to `symbols` function.  "reading" that string is done by sympy code.  The notation may look, in part, like python, but it is probably influenced by usage in other symbolic math languages.  Ulitmatelly it's just what the sympy developers thought would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of the [`symbols` function](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.symbol.symbols) is well written with plenty of examples, so I'm not going to repeat it here.

The "range syntax" is implemented by this function in order to reduce typing while creating indexed elements. Note that I used the word "elements" and not "symbols", because the `symbols` function can be used to create ordinary symbols, wild symbols (for pattern matching), undefined functions, indexed objects, etc. For example:

```py
s1, s2, s3, s4, s5 = symbols("s1:6")
f1, f2, f3, f4, f5 = symbols("f1:6", cls=Function)
i1, i2, i3, i4, i5 = symbols("i1:6", cls=Idx)
```

Note that:

1. I haven't used curly parentheses in the above examples.
2. there is no `_` (underscore) character between the actual name and the numeric subscript.
3. If you are using an interactive environment which render latex (for example, Jupyter Notebook), you will see that the above symbols and function will be rendered with a subscript. That's the default behavior of the `LatexPrinter`.

Underscores and curly parentheses can be used to create more complicated-looking symbols. For example, if I want to create a symbol representing the temperature of hydrogen inside a tank I would do something like this:

```py
T = symbols("T_{H_{2}}^{tank}")
T
```

[image]

This renders nicely on an interactive environment, but it would be very hard to understand on a non-interactive environment.

**EDIT to satisfy comment**: it really depends on what you are trying to achieve. For example, using a list of symbols:

```py
N = 6
z = symbols("z_{0:%s}" % N) # list of symbols
sum([z[(-1)**n + 1] for n in range(N)])
# out: 3*z_{0} + 3*z_{2}
```

or using an indexed object:

```py
N = 5
z = IndexedBase("z")
expr = Sum(z[(-1)**n + 1], (n, 0, N))
print(expr)
# out: Sum(z[(-1)**n + 1], (n, 0, 5))
print(expr.doit())
# out: 3*z[0] + 3*z[2]
```

If you look at the latex rendered on the screen, the last output of both examples are identical, yet they are conceptually very different.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Follow-up question:  For me, the main value of using z = symbols("z_{0:3}") is that I can do arithmetic operations with the subscripts, such as  z[(-1)**n + 1].  I don't be believe I can do that with e.g. s0, s1, s2 = symbols("s0:3") --- please correct me if I am wrong, really!   Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @davide_sd.  Follow-up question:  What's the difference between the symbols method vs indexedbase, in terms of performing symbolic calculation?  I looked up the documentation for indexedbase, and it seems that the main advantage is that in principle I can have an infinite list of indexed variables, whereas the symbols method would require that I prescribe the number of indices.  Shouid I infer from this that the indexedbase method would be slower?  THANKS!

Comment: Again, it really depends on what you are trying to achieve. Suppose you are dealing with a summation where the index goes from 0 to infinity: `IndexedBase` is not going to create an infinite number of elements, unless you instruct it to. On the other hand, you would potentially have to create an infinite list of symbols... Another advantage of `IndexedBase` is that you can easily substitute it with a SymPy's `Array` or `Matrix` of elements, whereas with a list of symbols you would have to create a dictionary mapping symbols to values, which might not always be trivial...